# Can't clone repository with git

Tags: git, beagleboard

I'm sshed into a BeagleBone Green Wireless and I'm trying to clone a repsitory into it

I've tried

```
git clone git@github.com:username/test.git
ssh: connect to host github.com port 22: Network is unreachable
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights and the repository exists.

git clone https://github.com/username/test.git
Cloning into 'test'...
fatal: unable to access 'https://github.com/username/test.git/': Couldn't connect to server
```

Is there any other way to clone a repository?

Comment: Is there anything wrong with your internet connection?

Comment: @LukeDinh But his internet has allowed him to post a question at least.

Comment: @andrewnagyeb hah yeah, I’m dumb

Comment: Is there anything wrong with the connection of your beagleboard? Can you try giving us the results of `ifconfig`?

Comment: wlan0     Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 2c:f7:f1:06:5a:a4
          inet addr:172.30.40.164  Bcast:172.30.43.255  Mask:255.255.252.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::2ef7:f1ff:fe06:5aa4/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST DYNAMIC  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:19470 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:3211 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000
          RX bytes:4204673 (4.0 MiB)  TX bytes:500274 (488.5 KiB)

Comment: I'm able to ping websites and able to use pscp to copy files to it.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can clone it elsewhere that has a network connection and copy that clone via whatever means you use to get files onto your Beagle Board.

But you should probably [fix your network connection on your Beagle Board](http://wiki.seeed.cc/BeagleBone_Green_Wireless/#step5-connect-your-bbgw-to-wi-fi) instead.